# Parse app crashes on iOS <8 in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, swift

I have a swift app that I am bridging from the Objective C Parse framework.

It does not crash in the simulator, but push notifications don't work in the simulator.

Here is the code:

```
Parse.setApplicationId("id", clientKey: "id")
    let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
```

It crashes on the following line without a error message:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I just tested it on my iPad (iOS 8) and now it is crashing there too?

Comment: you tried updating your xCode? to 6.1 Apple made some API updates on Swift...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it crash in iOS<8 its because -registerUserNotificationsSettings() work only on iOS8.

Try something like that :

```
let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)


if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector(@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:))){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}else{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationsTypes(notificationTypes)
}
```

Comment: It says unresolved identifier `registerUserNotificationSettings`

Comment: When I take out `@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)` and put in just `registerUserNotificationSettings`, then it says `'UIApplication does not have member named 'registerUserNotificationSettings'`